# php fwrite issue when accessing the file

Tags: php, cron, fwrite

Hi i have a issue with my script.

I'm writing file contents using below code..and saving a file in my directory which users can access

```
$File = fopen('help/gossipcom.html','w'); 
fwrite($File, $header1 . $title2 . $footer1);  
fclose($File);
```

This is **working perfectly**..

But i'm running this using **cron job**

if a **user access the file at the same time** when the **cron job runs**, it will show a **blank page**..How can i avoid this issue?.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you only need to write the file and you are not intending for appending it every time the cron runs.

What , i feel , you can do in this situation is you can create a temp file every time your cron runs with the name say

```
TEMP FILE - help/gossipcomtemp.html
```

Write your content in this file and after fclose() it, rename/mv the file with the actual name that is

```
MAIN FILE - help/gossipcom.html
```

This will , i think , ensure that your main file gets accessible when cron is running and this will not be locked both for writing and reading.

Answer (score 1):

Use temporary file for writing data and then rename it to gossipcom.html type.